# Why does a degree of freedom vanish from 3D to 2D in that tensor construction?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

Let's assume an arbitrary tensor in 3D coordinates: $g_{ij} $ with $i, j$ in $[1,3]$.
It shall be arbitrary, meaning *not* symmetric.
It has 9 entries which equals 9 degrees of freedom (dof).

Now, I want to find a graphical representation for that tensor. I find that construction useful: A point with six "legs" of arbitrary length. The opposite legs lie on the same line, respectively. The lengths of the legs make up 6 degrees of freedom and the angles between the lines make up further three degrees of freedom ( angles between (x, y), (y, z) and (x, z)) . The sum is 9, the same as the number of degrees of freedom of $g_{ij} $. Nice.

[image: point with legs attempt to visualize a tensor. C is just the central point (at which the tensor sits in the tensor field. X_1C, X_2C etc. are independent length (6 dof). three angles must be set to completely define the object (3 dof)]

However, if I go from 3D to 2D, something strange happens: One degree of freedom vanishes. In 2D, there are four entries in $g_{ij} $ with $i, j$ in $[1,2]$. But in the model "point with legs" as above, there are 5 degrees of freedom: 4 lengths and 1 angle.

Why it doesn't work for 2D? Or, if you want to say "it's just coincidence that it works at 3D and your model isn't actually supposed to work at all" - *why* does it work at 3D?

For a symmetric tensor like the metric tensor, this "summing up the degrees of freedom of directions and angles" works well for *every* number of dimensions. Only, because of the symmetry, the lengths of the opposite legs have to be the same.

Comment: Consider to include a diagram.

Comment: A diagram would certainly help. From your description, to me it seems there are only two independent angles (e.g. leg 1- leg 2, leg2 - leg 3).

Comment: In general, it seems that your construction gives, for $n=2d$ legs, $n$ lengths plus $d-1$ angles (plus one additional angle IF you also specify a fixed axis in the plane, and count fixed axis - leg 1 as another dof). In any case, the number of dofs is linear in $d$, not quadratic.

Comment: My construction gives 2d legs and d! / (2 (d-2)!) angles. The number of angles calculates as the number of possibilities to chose 2 out of d. For d=3 it's 3. Aha, then I got 1/2 d^2 +3/2 d degrees of freedom in my construction and d^2 dof in the tensor. Setting that equal results in d =3. Interesting. Therefore, d=3 is the only dimension where this model works/fits. For larger d, it's not sufficient: The arbitrary 4D- tensor has 4*4 =16 entries, but my model results in only 8 legs + 6 angles = 14 dof. Breaking the lines and allowing for additional angles helps probably...

Comment: Hm, okay, the angle of the third line is not really set but as well not completely arbitrary.... The third line lies on a cone around the first if the angle between third and first is set.

Comment: I believe it is a coincidence that your diagram works in 3D. Suppose you treat these as matrices; one way to visualize a matrix is to treat its columns as basis vectors (entries being coordinates). So, in 2D, you have two vectors sticking out of the origin, each with 2 degrees of freedom. One view is, each has two coordinates. Another is, each has a direction (an angle w/ resp. to the x-axis), and a length, and the angle *between* them is completely determined by their individual angles. 1/2

Comment: In your 2D visualization, there is no relationship between, say, pairs of lengths and the angle between the lines, so you have an extra degree of freedom. It may be strange to you that there should be such a constraint, but consider that you've yourself somewhat arbitrarily constrained certain pairs of legs to lie on the same line, thus reducing the degrees of freedom in terms of possible orientations. If you removed that constraint, you'd end up with (if I'm not mistaken) 12 degrees of freedom for your 3D case. 2/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OP's graphical representation of matrix DOF seems inspired by the fact that a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}~=~n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ DOF can be diagonalized $M=ODO^{-1}$ by a real orthogonal transformation. There are $n$ real eigenvalues (which we identify with lengths), and the orthogonal group $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ DOF (which we identify with angles).
2. If we identify OP's $n$ double-lengths with $n$ complex eigenvalues, then OP is considering a $$2n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}~=~\frac{n(n+3)}{2}$$ dimensional subset of complex symmetric $n\times n$ matrices that can be diagonalized by real orthogonal transformations.
3. The latter is different from the set of real $n\times n$ matrices with $$n^2$$ DOF that OP started with.