# Graphical representation of an arbitrary tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, models, visualization

I am interested in finding graphical models for tensors. To begin with, let's think about graphical models of tensors in 2D and 3D. If possible, I would be interested in the graphical representations of tensors in arbitrary numbers of dimensions as well.
In 3D, a *symmetric* tensor can be visualized using a spheroid (ellipsoid of rotation). That ellipsoid possesses one main direction (3 coordinates) and three perpendicular axes (3 lengths). That makes up in sum 6 degrees of freedom.

How can one visualise a *non-symmetric* tensor in 3D?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/788343/2451